# Get specific parts of a string based on specific words in the string php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string, who contains multiple values. A new line is recognised as | symbol. The values between | belong together.

Now, I am trying for example if IKK and Homo sapiens are present in the line, to return the other values in that line (96, NC_000001 , IKK , inhibitor of nuclear factor, IKK = IKKI).

I use explode function for separating the string based on | symbol. But if I use the explode function again now based , symbol. I got again an array. But if I now would look for homo sapiens & IKK and want to return the other values from that same line, I got stuck.

I have the following string:

```
    $var = 'IKK ,Homo sapiens,96, NC_000001 , IKK , inhibitor of nuclear factor, 
    IKK = IKKI |GAL4 ,Saccharomyces cerevisiae,85588,NC_00114 , GAL4 ,0, GAL81
    |TRP ,Influenza HA,0,0,0,0,0|TES,Influenza HA,5,0,TES,0,0';
```

My code:

```
function terms($result){
    $result = (explode("|",$result));
    $final = array_unique($result);
    return $final;
}
$test = terms($var);
foreach ($test as $key => $value){
    echo "key: $key -- value: $value"."<br \>\n"; 
    $res = explode(",",$value);
    foreach ($res as $v){
        echo "tester: >> $v"."<br \>\n"; 
    }
}
```

I probably should end up with something like this. But I don't find a way to get there. Is it even possible to get this structure?

```
if ($d[1] == "Homo sapiens" && $d[0] == "IKK"){
    $k = $d[2] # 96
    $s = $d[3] # NC_000001
 }
```

As end result I would like to save the values 96, NC_000001 , IKK , inhibitor of nuclear factor, IKK = IKKI separately again and again in a separate variable. 
$number = 96
$acc = NC_000001

Comment: return the other values but not "IKK" and "Homo Sapiens" ?

Comment: I can probably write you an answer using array_filter() but I need to know exactly how you need this done

Comment: I adapted my question, I hope it helped.

Comment: Edited my answer - let me know if works ok

Comment: Thanks very much, I will let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to white-spaces involved, I think you are unable to compare values.
Please try this :

```
<?php

$var = 'IKK ,Homo sapiens,96, NC_000001 , IKK , inhibitor of nuclear factor, 
    IKK = IKKI |GAL4 ,Saccharomyces cerevisiae,85588,NC_00114 , GAL4 ,0, GAL81
    |TRP ,Influenza HA,0,0,0,0,0|TES,Influenza HA,5,0,TES,0,0';

function terms($result){
    $result = (explode("|",$result));
    $final = array_unique($result);
    return $final;
}


function compare_terms($res){
    $d = array_map('trim',$res);
    if ($d[1] == "Homo sapiens" && $d[0] == "IKK") {
        $k = $d[2] ; 
        echo $k ."<br \>\n"; // 96
        $s = $d[3] ; 
        echo $s ."<br \>\n"; // NC_000001
    }
}


$test = terms($var);
foreach ($test as $key => $value){
    echo "key: $key -- value: $value"."<br \>\n"; 
    $res = explode(",",$value);
    compare_terms($res);
}
```

Here in the compare_terms function, we have applied trim function on each value of array  by using : 
**$d = array_map('trim',$res);**

Now we can compare values accordingly

Answer (score 1):

For this portion:

```
$res = explode(",",$value);
foreach ($res as $v){
    echo "tester: >> $v"."<br \>\n"; 
}
```

rewrite as

```
$filters = array("IKK", "Homo sapiens", .... "etc.");

$res = explode(",", $value);
$raw_filtered_res = array_filter($res, function ($v, $k) use($filters) {
    return !in_array($v, $filters);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);

if (count($res) !== count($raw_filtered_res)) {
    $filtered_res = array_values(array_diff($res, $raw_filtered_res));
    foreach ($filtered_res as $v) {
        echo "tester: >> $v"."<br \>\n"; 
    }
} else {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run it, so there very well could be syntax errors in here... but maybe something like this would suit your needs? A generic function to pass the string to (post pipe explode) with an array of terms the subsequent substring needs to have

```
function filterList($str, $needed = []){
    //str is the pre-exploded comma delimited string
    //needed are the terms required for the string to pass
    //needed terms are filtered out of the returned array
    $found = true;
    if(! is_array($needed)) $needed = [$needed];
    foreach($needed as $needs_str){
        if(stripos($str, $needs_str) === false){
            $found = false;
        }
    }
    if($found){
        return array_filter(explode($str, ','), function($item) use ($needed){
            return ! in_array($item, $needed);
        });
    }
    return [];
}
```

then use like

```
foreach ($test as $key => $value){
    $res = filterList($value, ["Homo sapiens","IKK"]);
    if(! empty($res)){
      //do something with res
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the initial problems is that your source data contains spaces all over the place, so the first part is to split the data down and `trim()` all the data. `array_walk()` is used to process each row at a time.

Then it's a case of filtering the result by the fields you want.  This is a case of checking if the `$filters` array is the same as the first fields in the terms(using `array_slice()` to extract the right number of fields), simply compare the arrays rather than individual fields, but this assumes the fields are in the same order.

Then with the output it process any results by removing the filter off the front (using `array_slice()` again ).

```
$var = 'IKK ,Homo sapiens,96, NC_000001 , IKK , inhibitor of nuclear factor,
    IKK = IKKI |GAL4 ,Saccharomyces cerevisiae,85588,NC_00114 , GAL4 ,0, GAL81
    |TRP ,Influenza HA,0,0,0,0,0|TES,Influenza HA,5,0,TES,0,0';

$terms = explode("|", $var);
array_walk($terms, function (&$line) {
    $line = explode(",",$line);
    $line = array_map('trim', $line);
});

$filters = ["IKK", "Homo sapiens"];
$output = array_filter($terms, function ($line) use ($filters)  {
    return $filters == array_slice($line, 0,count($filters));
});
array_walk($output, function (&$line) use ($filters) {
    $line = array_slice($line, count($filters));
});
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a concept of nested arrays. Each element of an array can be an array, too. So explode and iterate the lines, then explode the fields. You can use `array_map()` to clean up the field values:

```
$data = 
  'IKK ,Homo sapiens,96, NC_000001 , IKK , inhibitor of nuclear factor, IKK = IKKI |'.
'GAL4,Saccharomyces cerevisiae,85588,NC_00114 , GAL4 ,0, GAL81|'.
'TRP ,Influenza HA,0,0,0,0,0|TES,Influenza HA,5,0,TES,0,0';

$values = [];
foreach (explode('|', $data) as $line) {
  $values[] = array_map(
    function($field) {
      return trim($field);
    },
    explode(',', $line)
  );
}

var_dump($values);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "IKK"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "Homo sapiens"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "96"
    [3]=>
    string(9) "NC_000001"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "IKK"
    [5]=>
    string(27) "inhibitor of nuclear factor"
    [6]=>
    string(10) "IKK = IKKI"
  }
  [1]=> ...
```

So now that you have that list of arrays you can use `array_filter()`.

```
$filteredValues = array_filter(
  $values,
  function($fields) {
    return ($fields[0] === 'IKK' && $fields[1] === 'Homo sapiens');
  }
);

var_dump($filteredValues);
```

Or you use a `foreach()` to find the first line that matches your condition.

```
$searchedLine;
foreach ($values as $fields) {
  if ($fields[0] === 'IKK' && $fields[1] === 'Homo sapiens') {
    $searchedLine = $fields;
    break;
  }
}

var_dump($searchedLine);
```